# C# Optimized Merge Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, merge

I have a data pull service through which my C# application pulls data. Data is pulled in using multiple jobs and once the data request is complete, the data pull service calls the `notify` method which I have implemented in my application class.

The following is the `notify` method code. It just checks if results is non-empty then calls `mergeResults` in new thread.

```
public override void notify(List<IFields> results)
{
     if (!results.IsNullOrEmpty())
     {
         Task.Run(() => { mergeResults(results); });
     }
}
```

I am using a List to store final merge results.

```
List<IFields> mergedResults;
```

I am using `object mergeLock` for mutual exclusion.

Here's the merge logic I am using:

```
    public void mergeResults(List<IFieldsByPrePost> results)
    {
        lock (mergeLock)
        {
            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                if (mergedResults.Count > 0)
                {
                    var properties = mergedResults.First().getDiffProperties();
                    bool isMatch = false;
                    foreach (var mergedResult in mergedResults)
                    {
                        isMatch = true;
                        foreach (var property in properties)
                        {
                            var value1 = mergedResult.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(mergedResult).ToString();
                            var value2 = result.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(result).ToString();
                            if (value1 != value2) { isMatch = false; break; }
                        }
                        if (isMatch)
                        {
                            mergedResult.Count += result.Count;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!isMatch)
                    {
                        mergedResults.Add(result);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    mergedResults.Add(result);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The above logic works but it is very slow, whenever a large set of results is passed to the method.

Also, the `notify` method is called multiple times by the data pull service with different result sets, further slowing it down.

I am looking for a better approach to solve this problem.

**TLDR; This algorithm is slow, can anyone show me a way to make it run faster?**

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected results based on those sample inputs.

Comment: First you need to go with breakpoints to see which line is slow then recreate that function or use other.

Comment: It would also be great if you could be more specific than `very slow` and `large set of results`.

Comment: Have you consider using `Parallel.ForEach` instead of a `for` loop?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the reflection  approach is one reason for your performance issue. Why you need it? The `lock (mergeLock)` at the beginning of a long operation blocks the whole program, so the `Task.Run` seems to be useless

Comment: @TimSchmelter - We can't improve data pull service. Its something beyond our control. So notify method will get called by all means which will keep on spawning new threads and will call mergeResults method. But since lock is used right at the beginning of the method, only one thread is allowed at a time.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - You are correct on the reflection approach. I ran a performance profiler test and and can see that 49% of CPU cycles are spent just on getProperty() and getValue() method calls. The result set that we are receiving is of abstract type and can have any of the 10 different concrete class objects.  getDiffProperties() call is made to get the differentiating properties from that class to do the merge.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Yes correct about Task.Run() as well, I am looking for an approach to execute that method in a multi-threaded way, but don't want multiple threads to cause reader-writer problem.

Comment: Is instead of this `getDiffProperties();` thing writing a function like `IsMatch(IFieldsByPrePost post){...}` in your `IFieldsByPrePost` class an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest, that IFields and/or IFieldsByPrePost derive from

```
IEquatable<IFields> and/or IEquatable<IFieldsByPrePost>.
```

So you can just test equality with

```
IFields fields1;
IFieldsByPrePost fields2;
bool equal = fields1.Equals(fields2);
```

This way you get around the Reflection, which is slowing your code down.
Then its just

```
foreach (var result in results)
{
  if (!mergedResults.Any(x => x.Equals(result))
  {
    mergedResults.Add(result);
  }
}
```

I don't know, what you are doing with the

```
mergedResult.Count,
```

so I am ommiting this.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs on IEquatable. I will give this a try and post the outcome.

Comment: of course, you will have to compare the items in the Equals(other) method then. And if you just put your Refection Code in there, it won't help. But there you shoud have access to all fields (even private flields on the same class). Depending on the number of Classes, which implement IFields, this could be quite some work.

Comment: it worked like a charm. As all threads finish data pull, simultaneously merge is also complete. It just eliminated 3rd loop from the code. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Consider making `mergedResults` a HashSet and use `Contains` rather than `Any` to improve performance for large sets.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that sticks out to me first is that the `mergeResults` method isn't generic, so I'm not sure why reflection is necessary. Removing the lines:

```
var value1 = mergedResult.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(mergedResult).ToString();
var value2 = result.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(result).ToString();
if (value1 != value2) { isMatch = false; break; }
```

and using the direct property:

```
if(mergedResult.Property1 == result.Property1) { isMatch = false; break; }
```

could help.